# consulta sql para llenar tabla problema con un valor

Tags: mysql

Estoy intentanto llenar una tabla con valores desde un consulta y hago una consulta a la tabla entradas que obtiene una sumatoria que almaceno en la variable $entradas, pero cuando el valor de la sumatoria es igua a 0 me toma el valor del ultimo registro, donde deberia decir 0 dice 20 que es ultimo valor de la columna "Ingresado por proveedor" he intentado de todo....por favor si alguien puede ayudarme. gracias . adjunto codigo. La consulta esta dentro del while

```
     <table id="admproductos"  class="table table-hover table-bordered">
                <caption style="display: none;">Consulta de Productos de <?php echo $_SESSION['id_area1']; ?></caption>


                <thead >
                 <tr>

                  <th>Código</th>
                  <th>Nombre</th>
                  <th>Marca</th>
                  <th>Proveedor</th>
                  <th>Stock contratado</th>
                  <th >Ingresado x proveedor</th>
                  <th>Fecha de ingreso</th>
                  <th>Nº Expediente</th>
                  <th>Stock actual</th>
                  <th>Categoría</th>


                  <th>Editar-Entrada</th>




                </tr>
              </thead>

              <tbody>
                <?php
while ($arreglo = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

    $sql = "SELECT productos.id_producto as id_producto, SUM(cantidad_ent) as cantidad_ent  from entradas, productos where entradas.id_producto = '$arreglo[0]'  and entradas.id_area = '$id_area2' and entradas.id_user <> 0 group by id_producto";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        #$y = date("Y", strtotime($row['Fechas']));
        $entradas = $row['cantidad_ent'];

    }

    if ($arreglo[4] == $entradas and $arreglo[7] == 0) {
        echo "<tr style='background: #F5A9A9;'>";
    } elseif ($arreglo[4] < $entradas and $arreglo[7] == 0) {
        echo "<tr style='background: #F5A9A9;'>";
    } elseif ($arreglo[4] > $entradas and $arreglo[7] == 0) {
        echo "<tr style='background: #58D3F7;'>";
    } elseif ($arreglo[4] > $entradas and $arreglo[7] > 0) {
        echo "<tr style='background: #58D3F7;'>";
    } else {echo "<tr style='background: #F2F5A9;'>";}

    echo "<td style='min-width:40px;'>$arreglo[0]</td>";
    echo "<td style ='text-transform:uppercase;'>$arreglo[1]</td>";
    echo "<td style='max-width:80px; text-transform:uppercase'>$arreglo[2]</td>";
    echo "<td style='min-width:40px; text-transform:uppercase'>$arreglo[3]</td>";
    echo "<td style='max-width:60px;'>$arreglo[4]</td>";
    if ($entradas > 0) {
        echo "<td >$entradas</td>";} elseif ($entradas <= 0) {
        $entradas = 0;
    }

    echo "<td>$arreglo[5]</td>";
    echo "<td style='max-width:70px;'>$arreglo[6]</td>";
    echo "<td style='max-width:40px;'>$arreglo[7]</td>";

    echo "<td style='max-width:90px;'>$arreglo[8]</td>";

    echo "<th class='text-center' style='min-width: 110px; text-align: center; ' > <div class='btn-group'><a class='btn btn-info' href='edit_producto.php?id=$arreglo[0];?>'><i class='fa fa-lg fa-edit' title='Editar'></i></a><a class='btn btn-warning' href='ent_prod.php?id=$arreglo[0];?>'><i class='fa fa-lg fa fa-shopping-cart' title='Entradas'></i></a></div>
              </div></th>";

    echo "</tr>";

}

mysqli_close($conn);
mysqli_free_result($query);

?>
              </tbody>
```

// coloque un if a la variable $entradas para que cuando el valor de la suma sea 0 el valor de la variable sea también 0, nose si esta bien

Answer (score 0):

Lo logre de la siguiente manera coloque el if al final del contenido de los campos  echo "$arreglo[8]"; de esa manera se actualiza la tabla verifica la tabla una vez que los datos están cargados adjunto codigo:

```
 <tbody>
                <?php
while ($arreglo = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

    $sql = "SELECT productos.id_producto as id_producto, SUM(cantidad_ent) as cantidad_ent  from entradas, productos where entradas.id_producto = '$arreglo[0]'  and entradas.id_area = '$id_area2' and entradas.id_user <> 0 group by id_producto";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        #$y = date("Y", strtotime($row['Fechas']));
        $entradas = $row['cantidad_ent'];

    }

    if ($arreglo[4] == $entradas and $arreglo[7] == 0) {
        echo "<tr style='background: #F5A9A9;'>";
    } elseif ($arreglo[4] < $entradas and $arreglo[7] == 0) {
        echo "<tr style='background: #F5A9A9;'>";
    } elseif ($arreglo[4] > $entradas and $arreglo[7] == 0) {
        echo "<tr style='background: #58D3F7;'>";
    } elseif ($arreglo[4] > $entradas and $arreglo[7] > 0) {
        echo "<tr style='background: #58D3F7;'>";
    } else {echo "<tr style='background: #F2F5A9;'>";}

    echo "<td style='min-width:40px;'>$arreglo[0]</td>";
    echo "<td style ='text-transform:uppercase;'>$arreglo[1]</td>";
    echo "<td style='max-width:80px; text-transform:uppercase'>$arreglo[2]</td>";
    echo "<td style='min-width:40px; text-transform:uppercase'>$arreglo[3]</td>";
    echo "<td style='max-width:60px;'>$arreglo[4]</td>";
    $entradas = number_format($entradas, 2, '.', '');
    echo "<td >$entradas</td>";

    echo "<td>$arreglo[5]</td>";
    echo "<td style='max-width:70px;'>$arreglo[6]</td>";
    echo "<td style='max-width:40px;'>$arreglo[7]</td>";

    echo "<td style='max-width:90px;'>$arreglo[8]</td>";

    echo "<th class='text-center' style='min-width: 110px; text-align: center; ' > <div class='btn-group'><a class='btn btn-info' href='edit_producto.php?id=$arreglo[0];?>'><i class='fa fa-lg fa-edit' title='Editar'></i></a><a class='btn btn-warning' href='ent_prod.php?id=$arreglo[0];?>'><i class='fa fa-lg fa fa-shopping-cart' title='Entradas'></i></a></div>
              </div></th>";
    if ($entradas = 0) {
        $entradas = 0;
    }
    echo "</tr>";

}

mysqli_close($conn);
mysqli_free_result($query);

?>
              </tbody>
```

// al final antes del tr coloque el if y funcionó...gracias y espero les sirva se debe tener cuidado donde se verifican los datos